# rubyonrailsのプロジェクトのブラウザ表示ができません

Tags: ruby-on-rails

重複の可能性ありですが質問してみます。
rorのまったくの初心者ですがrubyとrailsをインストール後
`rails new sample` とした後
`rails s`を入力すると以下の結果となりlocalhost:3000を表示できません。

```
c:\rails>rails s
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
      [--skip-namespace], [--no-skip-namespace]            # Skip namespace (aff
ects only isolated applications)
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                        # Path to the Ruby bi
nary of your choice
                                                           # Default: C:/Ruby25-
x64/bin/ruby.exe
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                                # Path to some applic
ation template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                                # Preconfigure for se
lected database (options: mysql/postgresql/sqlite3/oracle/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlse
rver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                           # Default: sqlite3
      [--skip-yarn], [--no-skip-yarn]                      # Don't use Yarn for
managing JavaScript dependencies
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]                # Don't create a Gemf
ile
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                        # Skip .gitignore fil
e
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                    # Skip source control
 .keep files
  -M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]    # Skip Action Mailer
files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]    # Skip Active Record
files
      [--skip-active-storage], [--no-skip-active-storage]  # Skip Active Storage
 files
  -P, [--skip-puma], [--no-skip-puma]                      # Skip Puma related f
iles
  -C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]      # Skip Action Cable f
iles
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]            # Skip Sprockets file
s
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                  # Don't install Sprin
g application preloader
      [--skip-listen], [--no-skip-listen]                  # Don't generate conf
iguration that depends on the listen gem
      [--skip-coffee], [--no-skip-coffee]                  # Don't use CoffeeScr
ipt
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]          # Skip JavaScript fil
es
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]          # Skip turbolinks gem

  -T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                      # Skip test files
      [--skip-system-test], [--no-skip-system-test]        # Skip system test fi
les
      [--skip-bootsnap], [--no-skip-bootsnap]              # Skip bootsnap gem
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                  # Setup the applicati
on with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                                # Setup the applicati
on with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--rc=RC]                                            # Path to file contai
ning extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                              # Skip loading of ext
ra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--api], [--no-api]                                  # Preconfigure smalle
r stack for API only apps
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                  # Don't run bundle in
stall
      [--webpack=WEBPACK]                                  # Preconfigure for ap
p-like JavaScript with Webpack (options: react/vue/angular/elm/stimulus)

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.

c:\rails>cd sample

c:\rails\sample>rails s
Traceback (most recent call last):
        43: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        42: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
        41: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
        40: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
        39: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        38: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'

        37: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        36: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_boot
snap_lfi'
        35: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        34: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        33: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        32: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        31: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:
387:in `dispatch'
        30: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/inv
ocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        29: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/com
mand.rb:27:in `run'
        28: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        27: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        26: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
        25: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
        24: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
        23: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
        22: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        21: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'

        20: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        19: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_boot
snap_lfi'
        18: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        17: from c:/rails/sample/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        16: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:114:in `requi
re'
        15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in
 `require'
        14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in
 `each'
        13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in
 `block in require'
        12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in
 `each'
        11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in
 `block (2 levels) in require'
        10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
         9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'

         8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
         7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_boot
snap_lfi'
         6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
         5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw
32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw
32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
         3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
         2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
         1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cac
he/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/
sqlite3_native (LoadError)

c:\rails\sample>gem install sqlite3
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32
Parsing documentation for sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32
Done installing documentation for sqlite3 after 1 seconds
1 gem installed

c:\rails\sample>rails s
Traceback (most recent call last):
        43: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        42: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
        41: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
        40: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
        39: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        38: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'

        37: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        36: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_boot
snap_lfi'
        35: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        34: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        33: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        32: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        31: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:
387:in `dispatch'
        30: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/inv
ocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        29: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/com
mand.rb:27:in `run'
        28: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        27: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        26: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails
/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
        25: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
        24: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
        23: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
        22: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        21: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'

        20: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        19: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_boot
snap_lfi'
        18: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        17: from c:/rails/sample/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        16: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:114:in `requi
re'
        15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in
 `require'
        14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in
 `each'
        13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in
 `block in require'
        12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in
 `each'
        11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in
 `block (2 levels) in require'
        10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
         9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'

         8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
         7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_boot
snap_lfi'
         6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/boots
nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
         5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw
32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw
32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
         3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
         2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
         1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cac
he/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/
sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

Comment: https://railstutorial.jp/chapters/beginning?version=5.1#cha-beginning この辺りから読んでみた方が良いかと。

Comment: sqlite3 （gem ではなく、本体）をインストールする必要がありそうです。 windows だと、どうやってやるのだろう、、と思っています。